# Busybox on VMware ESXi: how to change syslogd options

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-esxi, syslog, busybox

**What I have:**
VMware **ESXi** 4.0 with **busybox** installed. Among busybox applets, I'm interested in syslogd. By default, it's running as busybox syslogd. I can see it via ps ax:

```
ps ax | grep syslog
4316 4316 busybox              syslogd
```

**What I need:**
To run syslogd with options. Like that:

```
busybox syslogd -R 10.30.35.67
```

**My questions:**

1. How to configure busybox, so that -R options comes to play at system startup? Is there any config file or something like that?
2. How to correctly change busybox syslogd options after the system has been started? How to stop busybox syslogd properly? How to start it with new options? I tried to kill busybox syslogd process (4316 in my case), but after restarting busybox syslogd -R 10.30.35.67 I can't see any syslogd-related process at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an easier way to configure remote syslogging that is even supported by VMware.

Within the VIC, select the ESXi server, then the "Configuration" tab.  From there, choose "Advanced Settings" and look for "Syslog" in the left-hand tree.  Enter your syslog destination within the setting "Syslog.Remote.Hostname".  Click OK and verify logs are making it to your destination properly.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Last question: how to do the same thing with VMware ESX 4.0? Unlike ESXi, I don't have Advanced Setting -> Syslog in VIC connected to ESX host. I tried to write a redirect rule in syslog.conf:*.debug  @10.30.35.67 but got an error: syslogd: sendto: operation not permitted.

Any idea?

Comment: Found the answer: http://www.tooms.dk/?page=http://www.tooms.dk/Tblog/Showblog1.asp%3FBlogID%3D200608232204307134. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Usually there is an etc directory which contains an rc file.  This is text and should have the startup parameters being passed to syslogd on busybox.  Also, the -R support must be compiled in.